# Data element description is not updated in SE16N

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I changed the DataElement of one column in SE11 transaction.

When I open the table at SE16N, the column name is the description of the older DataElement.

**How  do I  update the column with the new description?**

Example:

At first time, I created as this:

```
FIELD        DataElement         Description when show at SE16N
COD_PANEL    NUMC5               numc5
```

At second time, I alter the DataElement:

```
FIELD        DataElement         Description when show at SE16N
COD_PANEL    ZCOD_PANEL          numc5
```

If I open the table in other language, the new name it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it doesn't work is probably the language.
You have to change the values for every language separately.
Login with the language where you want to update and do the changes again.
Then it should work.

Otherwise, did you activate the changes?

Comment: The issue is independent of the language. And I assume the OP did activate, but that doesn't solve it (at least for me though).

Comment: Well, he wrote "If I open the table in other language, the new name it's correct.". so I think the issue is not independent from language....

Comment: @Philip Allgaier I'm not sure why you insist so much on how this is not what the asker wanted and that it doesn't solve the problem. I'd say it's for him to desice whether it solves his problem or not and if you think all this solutation are just wrong (what could be, maybe you're right), then why don't you offer your own solution? ;)

Comment: @CurlyB Because, unfortunately I haven't one. I am aware of that issue for a long time, and what I usually do is to manually remove the old DDIC description that is shown for an element (e.g. i a table structure), deliberately change a character in the DDIC element's name (so the system realizes that it doesn't exist) and then correct it. That forces the system to pull the new, correct description. But that approach is rather cumbersome. I am still hoping someone else has a nice trick at hand.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier that's an explanation I can live with and something that would make the question asked a real good one.

Comment: @Jay True, but at least I did interpret that as just a note, that it works in general, just not in the case of his question: In the same session with the same language. Changing the language, probably involves logging off and on, which might trigger some cache refreshes...

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction code [SE14](https://www.stechies.com/transaction-code-se-14) to adjust DDIC objects to changes

[image]

It updates all database attributes and their corresponding representation in DDIC.

Answer (score -1):

I usually do the following steps:

1. Manually ***remove the old description*** that is displayed.
2. Deliberately ***enter a typo*** in the used DDIC element name. This will make the system show an error message since that element does not exist.
3. ***Correct*** the ***DDIC element spelling***. The system now considers this a big enough change to pull in the correct description of the element.

*Result:* The description of the changed DDIC element is now shown.